# How to get Metadata for camelCase JsonFormatter

Tags: breeze

I am using the following in my Global.asax to change the formatting to camelCase on the client.

```
        // Change Json data to camelCasing
        var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

In addition, we are using Unity, and I have a Separate Service and a custom EFContextProvider class that resturns metadata, consumed in the Controller.  I assume that because I'm generating Metadata outside of the BreezeController, it then is returning the metadata in PascalCase, which my Code first DbContext is all using.

End result is that I get PascalCased Metadata(this seems incorrect from waht I expect) and camelCased entities from entityQueries but are not observable knockout properties.  Any tip or ideas why my entities are not observable would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a ContractResolver for this, Breeze handles this directly via it's NamingConvention class: See the NamingConvention discussion on this page. [Breeze Docs - NamingConvention](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata).

Basically, all you need to do is call:

```
 breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault(); // a convention can self-register as the default
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped, but I believe my full issue was also that I was returning an IQueryable which did not come from the EFContextManager.  This was because of Unity Injection.  I ended up creating a custom EFContextManager class and resolved that with Unity to get the correct IQueryable into the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this server side using the BreezeConfig.Instance.GetJsonSerializerSettings().ContractResolver.

```
public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "BreezeApi",
  routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
 );


 BreezeConfig.Instance.GetJsonSerializerSettings().ContractResolver 
                                        = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```